# Remove beginning of String with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I'm getting changing results from a method. It is everytime a String, but at the beginning of every String is written "String(xxx) *"Text of String...* ". The xxx depends on the number of characters inside of the String. I tried using regex to cut everything away before first appearance of " :

`(result.replace(/^.+?(\") /, ''))`

But I'm not sure if I used it correctly. I would also accept other approaches, which delete the beginning of the String in every case (independently of the length of the string).

Example:

return String: `'string(18) "This is an example"'`

And I just want to get the String without the stuff at the beginning, so:

```
'This is an example'
```

But the return (and therefore the number in the parenthesis) can vary. I want to cut this out in every case.

Comment: You've put your space after the quote instead of before it `var s = s.replace(/^.+? (\")/, '')`

Comment: You'll also want to remove the `"` at the end `.replace(/\"$/, "")`

Comment: or split it on the quotation marks `s.split('"')[1];`

Comment: @pilchard nice option, but it *might* need to handle quotes in the middle (OP doesn't indicate if these are possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the following regex:

```
/.+\)\s\"(.*)\"/
```

As follows:

- `.+` - one or any number of characters
- `\)\s\"` - until you reach `) "`
- `(.*)` - then capture everything
- `\"` - until you reach the final `"`

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const processString = (string) => {

  let processedString = string.replace(/.+\)\s\"(.*)\"/, '$1');

  console.log(processedString);
}


processString('string(18) "This is an example"');
processString('string(23) "This is another example"');
processString('string(25) "This is a "third" example"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
string.replace(/^.*? "|"$/g, '')
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/wjz99D/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   "                       ' "'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

JavaScript code:

```js
const string = 'string(18) "This is an example"';
console.log(string.replace(/^.*? "|"$/g, ''));
```